# How to filter nested data with EXTRACTJSONFIELD

Tags: sql, apache-kafka, ksqldb

The `PAYLOAD` column stores a Json stringified  value such as:

```
"{\"key\":{\"subkey\":\"subvalue\"}}"
```

Running the ksql statement

```
SELECT EXTRACTJSONFIELD(PAYLOAD, '$.key') AS key FROM my_stream WHERE (key => subkey = 'subvalue');
```

results to an error. Is there a way to filter so it returns only if `subkey` is equal to "subvalue" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a value from a nested key stored as a json string we specify a complete key's path as `$.key.subkey`:

```
SELECT EXTRACTJSONFIELD(PAYLOAD, '$.key.subkey') AS data_payload FROM my_stream;
```